# How to return ActiveRecord objects that have an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm sure there's an easy way to do this but have googled myself dry...

I have a model that has a has_many association

```
Object.rb
has_many :things
```

I want to basically write

```
Object.include? :things
```

And get a query response which contains all the objects that have at least one thing.

Also the same with a has_one..

Any ideas?

Comment: try `Object.includes(:things)`

Comment: That gives me everything. I just want the ones where the thing actually exists.

Comment: Could you let me know what does it return - `Object.includes(:things).references(:things)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Using `where` in Rails **3.2**:

```
# When *has_many* association:
Object.includes(:things).where("things.id IS NOT NULL")

# When *has_one* association:
Object.includes(:thing).where("things.id IS NOT NULL")
```

Note that, in `where` clause you need to use the actual table name.

Rails(Active Record) **4.0** and above adds `where.not` so you can do this:

```
Object.includes(:things).where.not('things.id' => nil)
# or
Object.includes(:things).where.not(things: {id: nil})
```

Comment: This didn't work for me as I'm using rails 3.

Equivalent is:

    Object.includes(:things).where('things.id IS NOT NULL')

Comment: try Object.includes(:things).where("things.id IS NOT NULL")

Comment: Giving this the green tick as I think the answer's slightly more complete.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this too

```
Object.includes(:things).where("things.id IS NOT NULL")
```